# listview with linked tables (many to many relationship)

Tags: android, listview

I have three tables:
Employees, Courses and Attendance (which links employees and courses).

I'm looking to get a listview (or other similar view), with a line for each employee and a 'column' for each course, with the date (from the link table) where attended. I'm struggling to work out how this can be done:
I can have run a query that gets a row for each employee-course combination, but that doesn't tie in to a row in the view for each employee (i.e. the query will return multiple rows for each listview row).
I can get the listview for each employee, but am not seeing how to then pull in the data for courses in via the linked table.

with no real direction I don't have code to post yet.

This can't be that uncommon a problem, but I'm not finding any examples: maybe I'm not thinking of the right phrases

What's best practice to achieve this sort of display?

Answer (score 0):

For me best display should be ExpandedListview. Let say you have Employee that attended 3 courses. In ExpandableListview you for your GroupView set Employee data and for child data just set the course that it attended with information that you have in your table. Like in this image :

[image]